# How to solve this javascript function

Tags: javascript, json

i am calling this function

```
   el=DOM.create({tag:"div",css:{backgroundColor:"#000000",color:"green"},html:"abc"});
   $("#fb_dv").append(el);
```

my function is here

```
DOM={
    create:function(data){
        if(data.tag){
            d=document;
            doc=d.createElement(data.tag);
            for(var v in data){
                 if(v=="css"){
                     for(key in data[v]){
                        prop=doc.style;
                        prop.key=data[v][key]
                     }
                 }
                 if(v=="html"){
                     doc.innerHTML=data[v]
                 }
            }

            return doc;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that this function is not setting css properties

Comment: The second line, using `$.append()` is your own library?

Comment: yes i have created it but problem is with DOM function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the for loop that should set the styles. You need to use the square bracket syntax to set the correct property:

```
for(key in data[v]){
    prop = doc.style;
    //prop.key = data[v][key]... change this to this:
    prop[key] = data[v][key];
}
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/4SxHG/).

As a side note, you have a lot of missing `var` statements so all of your variables are leaking into the global scope, and you also have a lot of missing semi-colons.

Comment: You are missing them after `prop.key=data[v][key]`, `doc.innerHTML=data[v]` and after the closing `}` of `DOM`.